# Proxy (or redirect?) request per location

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, proxy, redirect

Something like this works globally with mod_proxy:

```
ProxyPass /api/* http://localhost:8081/api
ProxyPassReverse /api/* http://localhost:8081/api
```

so all my client requests for `/api` are directed to `http://localhost:8081/api`

What if I got two locations like `localhost/site1/` & `localhost/site2/`
and I needed different redirection per site?all these apps request /api asynchronously

so visiting site1, 
an xhr call is made requesting /api, I would like **http://localhost:8081/api** to respond

for /site2 an xhr call is made requesting /api, I would like **http://localhost:9091/api** to respond

Can this be done with an .htaccess in each of those folders, or by global redirection?Do I need mod_rewrite with http Referrer rule or mod_proxy for this one?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having different, **location based proxy settings** is perfectly possible.

First, the [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) is not a [redirection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) i.e. location doesn't change. It is a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) that obtains the content from external source.

> As httpd receives a request from a client, the request itself is
>   proxied to one of these backend servers, which then handles the
>   request, generates the content and then sends this content back to
>   httpd, which then generates the actual HTTP response back to the
>   client.

Then, you can't use `ProxyPass` in `.htaccess` context, but it's possible to use it in `<Location>` context. Let's assume that you want `example.com/site1/api` to be proxied to `localhost:8081/api` and `/site2/api` to `localhost:8082/api`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    <Location "/site1/api/">
        ProxyPass "http://localhost:8081/api/"
        ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:8081/api/"
    </Location>

    <Location "/site2/api/">
        ProxyPass "http://localhost:8082/api/"
        ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:8082/api/"
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Your alternative syntax is also possible directly in the `<VirtualHost>` context, but a) *it can carry a performance penalty when present in very large numbers* and b) something must be left to homework.

---

*Further discussion based on additional details from comments & edit on the question.*

While possible, **I can't recommend the following as a viable solution**, as having always a working HTTP referer on every request isn't guaranteed. For example, if any API request has reference to another `/api` URL, the referer might be `/api` or empty instead of `/siteN`. Having different URLs for API calls from different sites, like in my first solution, is much more manageable and reliable.

If you need to share the common URL `/api` between **XMLHttpRequests (XHR)** from `/site1` and `/site2` and proxy them to different back-ends based on referer (if your API requests sends referer), it might be possible to [Use mod_rewrite for Proxying](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html) distinguish the request from different sites with

```
    RewriteEngine  on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://example\.com\/site1/
    RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ "http://localhost:8081/api/$1" [P]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://example\.com\/site2/
    RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ "http://localhost:8082/api/$1" [P]
```

Comment: thanks, Not sure if this answers my question, I want to distinguish site1 and site2 location not api1 and api2, so, when requesting /api/ for site1 proxy to /api1, when requesting /api/ from site2 proxy to /api2, if that makes sense

Comment: imagine that all clients hit /api/, but they need to get different responses depending on their location (site1/site2)

Comment: What do you mean here by "location"? Is there two applications hosted in `example.com/site1` and `example.com/site2`, both accessing `example.com/api`?

Comment: yes, the /api URL may be the same on both, but they must get different responses

Comment: It may be difficult to distinguish these queries from each other. One could use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}` or `RewriteCond  "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}"` to rewrite `/api` to `/api1` or `/api2`, but that requires this kind of assumptions can be made. I think it would be easier to have separated `/api1` and `/api2` to serve them.

Comment: so you could write those redirects inside site1 and site2 in respective .htaccess files, right? trying to make this work with no luck so far..

Comment: I don't understand. Is there a site `/site1` or is `:8081/api` supposed to be reached when requesting `/site1`? Describe what kind of request the application uses.

Comment: ok you are probably right, u land at /site1 and theres an XHR request to /api (must actually get http://localhost:8081/api/).
You land at /site2 and theres an XHR request to /api (must actually get http://localhost:8082/api/)

Comment: I think I got it now. I've added some additional hints, including reasoning for why proxying based on location works better than checking for other conditions.

Comment: wow thanks, great answer, trying the last option and struggling with apache error "Cannot parse condition clause: syntax error, unexpected T_ID, expecting $end" ..:/

Comment: FYI for the second I get "ProxyPass cannot occur within <If> section"

Comment: Thanks for testing. I removed that alternative. Haven't really used `<If>` myself.